# Java : SQL syntax error for entering values in Table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

i am trying to add two methods to `withdraw and deposit`  money in Bank Class . My `Database name is javatest` .  `table name is bank` and following is the code  . Problem is that when i run this code compiler  says   `You have an error in your SQL syntax;`  i did check code 3-4 times but really unable to get it please help me with it .

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    Connection connection= null ; 
    Statement stmt = null ; 
    try 
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest","root","");
        stmt= connection.createStatement();
        withdrawfromchecking(connection, stmt, new BigDecimal(100), 1); 
        Depositinsaving(connection, stmt, new BigDecimal(444), 1);
        stmt.executeBatch();
        System.out.println("Done");
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {e.getMessage();}
    catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    finally 
    {
        if(connection!=null){try {connection.close();} catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}}
        if(stmt!=null){try {stmt.close();} catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}}
    }
}


public static void withdrawfromchecking(Connection connection ,Statement stmt,  BigDecimal amount , int id ) throws SQLException
{
    stmt.addBatch("UPDATE bank  SET checkingbalance = checkingbalance-"+amount+"WHERE id="+id);
}
public static void Depositinsaving(Connection connection ,Statement stmt,  BigDecimal amount , int id ) throws SQLException
{
    stmt.addBatch("UPDATE bank  SET savingbalance = savingbalance+ "+amount+"WHERE id="+id);
}
}
```

Error comes for this line - `stmt.executeBatch();` when i run program

**EDIT :   Exact error statement**

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'id =1' at line 1    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:1193)    at
>   MyPackage.BankAccount.main(BankAccount.java:24)

**in my code (line 24 is stmt.executeBatch();**

Answer (score 3):

In both of your SQLs, there is no space between the concatenation of the amount and the word `WHERE` -- it looks like this: `checkingbalance-100WHERE id=`.

Place a space before both `WHERE` words.

```
stmt.addBatch("UPDATE bank  SET checkingbalance = checkingbalance-"
  //       +- Add space here
  //       v
  +amount+" WHERE id="+id);
```

Comment: That's all I can tell from just your Java code.  Run your generated SQL statements directly in the database to determine if they're correct.

Comment: please check my edited post , i did add exact error statement if it clears anything .

Answer (score 1):

Change your **withdrawfromchecking** and **Depositinsaving** methods to this:

```
public static void withdrawfromchecking(Connection connection, Statement stmt, BigDecimal amount, long id) throws SQLException{
        statement.addBatch("UPDATE bank SET checkingBalance = checkingBalance - " +amount+ " WHERE id =" + id);
    }

    public static void Depositinsaving(Connection connection, Statement stmt, BigDecimal amount, long id) throws SQLException{
        statement.addBatch("UPDATE bank SET savingBalance = savingBalance + " +amount+ " WHERE id =" + id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to put the update statement in a string and examine the value after concatenation.

Ideally you should be using parameterized [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of dynamically concatenating the sql.